# Error in fromJSON(paste(raw.data, collapse = "")) : unclosed string

Tags: json, r

I am using the R package `rjson` to download weather data from Wunderground.com. Often I leave the program to run and there are no problems, with the data being collected fine. However, often the program stops running and I get the following error message:

```
Error in fromJSON(paste(raw.data, collapse = "")) : unclosed string
In addition: Warning message:
In readLines(conn, n = -1L, ok = TRUE) :
  incomplete final line found on 'http://api.wunderground.com/api/[my_API_code]/history_20121214pws:1/q/pws:IBIRMING7.json'
```

Does anyone know what this means, and how I can avoid it since it stops my program from collecting data as I would like?

Many thanks,

Ben

Comment: Are you sure that the package is called `fromJSON`?  Both the `rjson` and `RJSONIO` packages have functions with that name, but I can't find a package called that.

Comment: Yes - sorry - you are correct. It is rjson.

Answer (score 2):

I can recreate your error message using the `rjson` package.

Here's an example that works.

```
rjson::fromJSON('{"x":"a string"}')
# $x
# [1] "a string"
```

If we omit a double quote from the value of `x`, then we get the error message.

```
rjson::fromJSON('{"x":"a string}')
# Error in rjson::fromJSON("{\"x\":\"a string}") : unclosed string
```

---

The `RJSONIO` package behaves slightly differently.  Rather than throwing an error, it silently returns a `NULL` value.

```
RJSONIO::fromJSON('{"x":"a string}')
# $x
# NULL
```

Comment: Be careful with this.  You'll still have to check for any `NULL` values and think about how to handle them.  The alternative is using `rjson` and wrapping the call to `fromJSON` inside `try` or `tryCatch`.